# npm Package.json not update devDependencies

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, npm-install

I am using NPM version 3.10.9 
When I run the following command from the project root, it installs But in package.json not upadeted devDependencies. can i do as manual.

Or any other solution.

```
npm i material-design-lite --save-dev
```

After install Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have your `package.json` open in your text editor when you are running the install command? If so, close it and try re-running the install command. Then check your `package.json`.

Comment: Tried Not working

Comment: No idea then...

Comment: if i create package.json in comment line after install some-thinking fine but if i edit some-thinking in editor After that not working. any idea

Comment: It doesn't matter whether package.json is open or not , the problem is something else